# OpenCV camera calibration?

Tags: android, opencv, camera-calibration

I am running OpenCV camera calibration sample in Android to calibrate my phone camera. I have printed asymmetric circle for calibration. Normally, we have to know the actual size of checkerboard and set it in the coding. So, I am wondering is it necessary to set it? If yes, is it set the *mSquareSize* variable in *CameraCalibrator.java*? Is the size the radius of circle in meter?

Comment: afaik, it is not necessary if you are not interested in the right focal distance. Do you just want to compute the distortion coefficients?

Comment: Actually I want the right focal distance too. So, should I set the mSquareSize in CameraCalibrator.java as the radius of circle in meter?

Comment: mm afaik, but I guess the unit will just change the scale